# Запретить доступ к просмотру определенной директории

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Есть такой `.htaccess` код:

```html
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|log|txt|rtf)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
 Allow from 192.168.0.101
 Allow from 192.168.0.100
 Allow from 192.168.0.102
 Allow from 93.75.31.82
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Но как я понял запрет по IP - не очень хорошая идея. У меня в файле `.htpasswd` есть пользователь `Administrator` т.е я, и мне нужно, чтобы при  директории `/en/reg_auth_rec_del/ajax` оно запрашивало пароль. С файлами такое действие видел, с директориями – нет. Как это реализовать??

Comment: почему это по IP не оч хорошая идея? Хотя.. глядя на файлы - для половины это просто бесполезная идея :)

Comment: @SeVlad Ну да, но когда в txt и rtf будет находится заметка (ну или что-то вроде этого) то это не так уж и бесполезно.

Comment: Но я так и не разобрался как запретить доступ к директории.

Comment: для ОС в целом нет разницы - файл или каталог. Доступы/запреты реализуются одинаково. По паролю - гугли "базовая авторизация". Но судя по htpasswd (только вот в документрут он  не должен быть) она уже имеется.